# Concatenating a CSS Class in a PHP Loop

Tags: php, css

I want to add a `class=active` to the current page im on with php

class_navigation.php

```
$menu = array(
  'home'  => array('text'=>'Home',  'url'=>'?p=home'),
  'away'  => array('text'=>'About',  'url'=>'?p=about'),
  'about' => array('text'=>'Contact', 'url'=>'?p=contact'),
);

class class_navigation {
  public static function GenerateMenu($items) {
    $html = "<nav>\n";

foreach($items as $item) {
      $class ="";
      if ($page == $item) {
          $class = "class='active'";
       }
      $html .= "<a href='{$item['url']}' ".$class.">{$item['text']}
      </a>\n";
    }
    $html .= "</nav>\n";
    return $html;
  }
};
```

nav.php

```
<?php 
    echo class_navigation::GenerateMenu($menu); 
?>
```

index.php

```
require_once('class/class_navigation.php');
require_once('includes/head.php');
require_once('includes/nav.php');

switch($_GET['p']){
         case "home":
              $page = 'home';
              include_once('pages/home.php');
              break 1;
         case "about":
              $page = "about";
              include_once('pages/about.php');
              break 1;
         case "contact":
              $page = "contact";
              include_once('pages/contact.php');
              break 1;    
    }

require_once('includes/footer.php');
```

Comment: you want this `$html .= "<a href='{$item['url']}' ".$class.">{$item['text']}
          </a>\n";` ? where `$class = 'class="active"';`

Comment: Ya but what how can I do the if statement?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33364700/4323504

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `$page` in `switch` and modify your class to this.

- Now `GenerateMenu` gets current page with `$page = $_GET['p'];`
- Compares it to `url` value in your array.
- `parse_str(substr($item['url'], 1));` parses this url and you will get `$p` equaling to `home`, if url is `'?p=home'` etc.

---

```
<?php
class class_navigation {
    public static function GenerateMenu($items) {
        $html = "<nav>\n";
        $page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : '';

        foreach($items as $item) {
            $class = "";

            parse_str(substr($item['url'], 1));

            if ($page == $p) {
                $class = " class='active'";
            }

            $html .= "<a href='{$item['url']}'".$class.">{$item['text']}</a>\n";
        }

        $html .= "</nav>\n";
        return $html;
    }
}
```